# Milnor Number of real and imaginary parts of holomorphic germs?

Tags: singularity-theory, several-complex-variables

By performing some computations using the Singular software, I've noticed the following pattern: if $\mu$ is the Milnor Number of a holomorphic germ $f\in \mathcal{O}_n$ at the origin, then the [Milnor number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milnor_number) of its real and imaginary parts are equal and are $\mu^2$, that is,
$$
\mu_{(\mathcal{R}e(f),0)} = \mu_{f,0}^2  
$$

By Milnor number of the real part of $f$, I mean $u=\mathcal{R}e(f)$ as a germ of real analytic function of $2n$ real variables (the real and imaginary parts of each complex variable). If $\mathcal{A_{2n}}$ is the ring of germs of such real analytic functions, then
$$
\mu_{(\mathcal{R}e(f),0)}=\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\mathcal{A}_{2n}}{\left<\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},..., \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y_1},..., \frac{\partial u}{\partial y_n}\right> }
$$

I would like to know if there's any generalisation to this. I've tried using some direct sum properties on ideals but got nowhere. I suspect there might be some tensor products involved, but also got nowhere.

Comment: On [mathoverflow.se] it is generally recommended to use at least one top-level tag, see: [Why are MO tags formatted as they are?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1457) and [Frequently asked questions about tagging on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075#1076). I am not familiar with the topic, so I should leave the choice of tags to the OP and to more experienced users. (I considered ([tag:ag.algebraic-geometry]) and ([tag:cv.complex-variables]), but maybe there are more suitable choices of tags.